# Changing characters in a data frame to numeric with if-function

Tags: r, dataframe, character, numeric

For example, i have this dataframe and i wanna change characters into numbers:

```
x<-c("a","b","c","a","a","a","c","b","b","a","c","a","b","b","c")
y<-rnorm(15)
z<-rnorm(15)
data<-data.frame(x,y,z)
```

I know this way:

```
data$x<-factor(data$x,levels = c("a","b","c"),labels = c(1,2,3))
```

but if i have more characters it will be take a lot. I wanna learn how can i change it with if-function.

Comment: But, if it an if/else, wouldn't it takes a lot than the `factor` labels.  Here you just need `as.numeric(data$x)`

Comment: `match(x, sort(unique(x)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works without relying on factors:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  mutate(x = group_indices(.,x))

# A tibble: 15 x 3
       x       y      z
   <int>   <dbl>  <dbl>
 1     1  1.61    0.865
 2     2 -0.424  -0.939
 3     3 -0.773  -0.558
 4     1  0.108   0.336
 5     1 -0.219   1.82
```

Answer (score 1):

We can just use

```
as.numeric(data$x)
#[1] 1 2 3 1 1 1 3 2 2 1 3 1 2 2 3
```

If it needs to be encoded in the occurence of `unique` elements

```
as.numeric(factor(data$x, levels = unique(data$x)))
#[1] 1 2 3 1 1 1 3 2 2 1 3 1 2 2 3
```

---

If we are okay to use packages, `.GRP` from `data.table` can be helpful

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, x1 := .GRP , x]
```